# CosmosDB Graph: How to update vertex having property with multiple values using gremlin?

Tags: gremlin, azure-cosmosdb

According to cosmosDB graph documentation, a vertex can have property with multiple values. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin-support

So while adding vertex if we define multiple values for a property, it gets added.

Suppose my query is :

```
g.addV('employee').property('id', 'john').property('country', 'USA').property('country', 'India')
```

Result is:

```
[{"id":"john","label":"employee","type":"vertex","properties":{"country":
    [{"id":"5dc2aaf6-cb11-4d4a-a2ce-e5fe79d28c80","value":"USA"},
     {"id":"fcf4baf6-b4d5-45a3-a4ba-83a859806aef","value":"India"}]}}]
```

But while updating vertex, if we update a property with multiple values.

Query is:

```
g.V('john').property('country', 'USA').property('country', 'India').property('country', 'China')
```

Result is:

```
[{"id":"john","label":"employee","type":"vertex","properties":{"country":
    [{"id":"7e5d9847-31e5-4a59-82f9-b78e744420a1","value":"China"}]}}]
```

How to update this property with multiple values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing the `list` keyword that will allow you to add additional properties.

[I'd recommend reading the Tinkerpop docs on VertexProperties](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#vertex-properties)

```
g.V('john').property(list, 'country', 'USA')
   .property(list, 'country', 'India')
   .property(list, 'country', 'China')
```

Comment: np, glad I could help

Comment: Using list keyword allows me to add additional properties but what if I want to change the existing value like from 'India' to 'China' in given query:

g.addV('employee').property('id', 'john').property('country', 'USA').property('country', 'India')

Can I do that?

Comment: Are you trying to change the value of a property from a list or just the single one? The query looks slightly different depending on which you want to do

Comment: I want to change the value of a property from a list. Suppose i have 2 values for property "country": USA & India and i want to change the value from 'India' to 'China'. What will be query for that?

Comment: @JagratiModi If you make a new question I'll answer it there. Better to answer it where it's easier for other people to see and learn from it

Comment: pretty well hidden in some examples I have to say.